# How do you implement a prompt that waits for an attachment or a text response?

Tags: botframework

You can use *builder.Prompts.attachment()* or *builder.Prompts.text()* but each of these wait only for its specific type of expected input. How do you wait to any type of message ?

Comment: you will need to build your own prompt by extending the underlying class of these PromptDialogs

Comment: yep. that's pretty clear. was looking to see if there's any other more elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have to be specific in the type of input you expect from the user. I recommend you use PrompDialog.Choice to give the user a choice of what type of message they want to use  (choice of attachment / text etc), and you can then send a reply that accepts that type of message

Comment: thanks but that's obvious and not a good solution as far as user experience goes.